# Make a shortcut on the Desktop with a custom icon

Tags: macos, finder, applescript, monterey

I used a symlink to make a shortcut on the desktop to a file

```
ln -s "~/My Scripts/start.sh" "Go go gadget hammer"
```

But realised I can't set an icon on a symlink.

So I used [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23902183/3310334) to make an alias:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to make new alias at (path to desktop folder) to (("~/My Scripts/start.sh") as POSIX file)'
```

But I get this error

```
Finder got an error: Can't make class alias. (-2710)
```

How can I make a shortcut on the desktop and also give it a custom icon eventually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a shortcut on the Desktop with a custom icon as simply as this:

1. In Finder, right-click the file you want the alias to point to and select "Make Alias"
2. Move the alias to the Desktop and give it whatever name you want (using Finder)
3. Assuming the icon you want to set is a PNG, open the image file in Preview and select Edit > Copy. This might work with many other image types too.
4. Right-click the alias and choose Get Info, then click the icon in the top left, and in Finder's menu bar select Edit > Paste. This will paste the image in as the file's icon.

Now you have an alias that has a custom icon.

Answer (score 0):

This following code should give you a basic idea

```
tell application "Finder"
    set aliasFile to make new alias file ¬
        at folder (path to desktop folder) ¬
        to alias ((path to home folder as text) & "My Scripts:start.sh") with properties ¬
        {name:"Go go gadget hammer"}
end tell
```

Comment: At line 3 I get "expected end or end tell but found parameter name

Comment: Copy the code exactly how it is. Looks to me as if you forgot to paste the last line... the `end tell`